2D mesh for eletrical machine with gmsh using python
enter image description here
I am making a rotor for an induction electric machine so there is the outer circle and the inner hole where the shaft goes through. Also there is the induction rotor bars for that I made a code that generates a circular padron to automaticaly generate them but I am new to Gmsh and never handle mutiple surfaces and subdomains. They are being bunch up together after the first one, and if I mesh it the rotor bar geometries are being ignored the error is:
Error:
: Unknown OpenCASCADE curve with tag 5

: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Downloads\\padrao circular.geo', line 41: Could not add curve loop : Unknown OpenCASCADE curve loop with tag 16

Here is the output GEO file (it continues the padron after the second rotor):

SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

// Define Constants
r_rlm = 0.31; // Radius of the rotor
r_shaft = 0.08; // Radius of the shaft
rbr_width1 = 0.0143; // First width of the rotor bar
rbr_width2 = 0.03; // Second width of the rotor bar
rbr_height = 0.0935; // Height of the rotor bar
rbr_y = 0.1786; // Y coordinate of the center of rotor bars
rbr_y2 = 0.0834; // Y coordinate of the displaced center of rotor bars

Circle(1) = {0, 0, 0, 0.31, 0, 2*Pi}; // Rotor circle, centered at (0, 0)
Circle(2) = {0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 2*Pi}; // Shaft circle, centered at (0, 0)

// Create line loops
Line Loop(3) = 1; // Outer circle
Line Loop(4) = -2; // Inner circle, note the negative sign

// Create a plane surface for the main domain
Plane Surface(5) = {3, 4};

// Assign a physical surface for the main domain
Physical Surface("MainDomain") = {5};

    // Rotor 1 angle = pi/8.0*0

    Point(6) = {0.00715, 0.1786, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the right side
    Point(7) = {-0.00715, 0.1786, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the left side
    Point(8) = {0.015, 0.262, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the right side
    Point(9) = {-0.015, 0.262, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the left side
    Point(10) = {0.0, 0.2721, 0, 1.0}; // Top point
    
    //
    Line(11) = {7, 6};
    Line(12) = {6, 8};
    Line(13) = {8, 10};
    Line(14) = {10, 9};
    Line(15) = {9, 7};

    Line Loop(16) = {11, 12, 13, -5, -6};
    Plane Surface(17) = {16};
    Physical Surface("Rotor1") = {17};
    Physical Surface("Rotor1_Subdomain") = 17;

    
// End Rotor 1

    // Rotor 2 angle = pi/8.0*1

    Point(18) = {-0.00715, 0.1786, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the right side
    Point(19) = {0.015, 0.262, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the left side
    Point(20) = {-0.015, 0.262, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the right side
    Point(21) = {0.0, 0.2721, 0, 1.0}; // Point on the left side
    Point(22) = {-0.06174152236294933, 0.1677410710479262, 0, 1.0}; // Top point
    
    //
    Line(23) = {19, 18};
    Line(24) = {18, 20};
    Line(25) = {20, 22};
    Line(26) = {22, 21};
    Line(27) = {21, 19};

    Line Loop(28) = {23, 24, 25, -5, -6};
    Plane Surface(29) = {28};
    Physical Surface("Rotor2") = {29};
    Physical Surface("Rotor2_Subdomain") = 29;

    
// End Rotor 2

And here is the Python code:
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define the initial and final angles in terms of pi notation
n=16/2 #numero de barras de rotor
initial_angle_pi = 1/n  # Initial angle in pi notation
final_angle_pi = 2  # Final angle in pi notation
step_angle_pi = 1/n  # Angle increment per step in pi notation

# Convert pi notation angles to radians
initial_angle = initial_angle_pi * math.pi
final_angle = final_angle_pi * math.pi
step_angle = step_angle_pi * math.pi

def cartesian_to_polar(x, y):
  """
  Transforms Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

  Args:
      x: The x-coordinate.
      y: The y-coordinate.

  Returns:
      A tuple containing the polar coordinates (radius, angle in radians).
  """
  radius = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
  angle = math.atan2(y, x)
  return radius, angle

def polar_to_cartesian(radius, angle):
  """
  Converts polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

  Args:
      radius: The radius in polar coordinates.
      angle: The angle in radians in polar coordinates.

  Returns:
      A tuple containing the Cartesian coordinates (x, y).
  """
  x = radius * math.cos(angle)
  y = radius * math.sin(angle)
  return x, y

r_rlm = 0.31 # Radius of the rotor
r_shaft = 0.08 # Radius of the shaft
rbr_width1 = 0.0143 # First width of the rotor bar
rbr_width2 = 0.03 # Second width of the rotor bar
rbr_height = 0.0935 # Height of the rotor bar
rbr_y = 0.1786 # Y coordinate of the center of rotor bars
rbr_y2 = 0.0834 # Y coordinate of the displaced center of rotor bars

# Create the points
Point_3 = (rbr_width1/2, rbr_y)  # Point on the right side
Point_4 = (-rbr_width1/2, rbr_y)  # Point on the left side
Point_5 = (rbr_width2/2, rbr_y+rbr_y2)  # Point on the right side
Point_6 = (-rbr_width2/2, rbr_y+rbr_y2)  # Point on the left side
Point_7 = (0, rbr_y + rbr_height)  # Top point

# Create the array of points
points = [Point_3, Point_4, Point_5, Point_6, Point_7]

# Convert the points to polar coordinates
polar_points = []
for point in points:
  radius, angle = cartesian_to_polar(point[0], point[1])
  polar_points.append((radius, angle))

rotated_points = []

# Append original points to rotated_points
for point in points:
    rotated_points.append(point)

# Rotate the points
current_angle = initial_angle
while current_angle <= final_angle:
    for i in range(len(points)):
        radius, angle = polar_points[i]
        rotated_x, rotated_y = polar_to_cartesian(radius, angle + current_angle)
        rotated_points.append((rotated_x, rotated_y))
    current_angle += step_angle

points.clear()

# Convert the points back to cartesian coordinates
for point in rotated_points:
  x, y = point
  points.append((x, y))

points = np.array(points)
x_coords = points[:, 0]
y_coords = points[:, 1]

# Plot the rotated points
plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'o')
plt.xlim(-r_rlm, r_rlm)
plt.ylim(-r_rlm, r_rlm)
plt.show()

output_text = ""

# Initial block of text
initial_block = f"""
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

// Define Constants
r_rlm = {r_rlm}; // Radius of the rotor
r_shaft = {r_shaft}; // Radius of the shaft
rbr_width1 = {rbr_width1}; // First width of the rotor bar
rbr_width2 = {rbr_width2}; // Second width of the rotor bar
rbr_height = {rbr_height}; // Height of the rotor bar
rbr_y = {rbr_y}; // Y coordinate of the center of rotor bars
rbr_y2 = {rbr_y2}; // Y coordinate of the displaced center of rotor bars

Circle(1) = {{0, 0, 0, {r_rlm}, 0, 2*Pi}}; // Rotor circle, centered at (0, 0)
Circle(2) = {{0, 0, 0, {r_shaft}, 0, 2*Pi}}; // Shaft circle, centered at (0, 0)

// Create line loops
Line Loop(3) = 1; // Outer circle
Line Loop(4) = -2; // Inner circle, note the negative sign

// Create a plane surface for the main domain
Plane Surface(5) = {{3, 4}};

// Assign a physical surface for the main domain
Physical Surface("MainDomain") = {{5}};
"""

output_text += initial_block

# Loop through angles
index = 0
current_angle = initial_angle
angle_index = 1  # Starting index
point_index = 6  # Starting point index
while current_angle <= final_angle:
    cos_val = math.cos(current_angle)
    sin_val = math.sin(current_angle)

    #  point block
    point_block = f"""
    // Rotor {angle_index} angle = pi/{n}*{angle_index-1}

    Point({point_index}) = {{{points[index, 0]}, {points[index, 1]}, 0, 1.0}}; // Point on the right side
    Point({point_index+1}) = {{{points[index+1, 0]}, {points[index+1, 1]}, 0, 1.0}}; // Point on the left side
    Point({point_index+2}) = {{{points[index+2, 0]}, {points[index+2, 1]}, 0, 1.0}}; // Point on the right side
    Point({point_index+3}) = {{{points[index+3, 0]}, {points[index+3, 1]}, 0, 1.0}}; // Point on the left side
    Point({point_index+4}) = {{{points[index+4, 0]}, {points[index+4, 1]}, 0, 1.0}}; // Top point
    """
    output_text += point_block

    #  line block and surfaces
    line_block = f"""
    //
    Line({point_index+5}) = {{{point_index+1}, {point_index}}};
    Line({point_index+6}) = {{{point_index}, {point_index+2}}};
    Line({point_index+7}) = {{{point_index+2}, {point_index+4}}};
    Line({point_index+8}) = {{{point_index+4}, {point_index+3}}};
    Line({point_index+9}) = {{{point_index+3}, {point_index+1}}};

    Line Loop({point_index+10}) = {{{point_index+5}, {point_index+6}, {point_index+7}, -5, -6}};
    Plane Surface({point_index+11}) = {{{point_index+10}}};
    Physical Surface("Rotor{angle_index}") = {{{point_index+11}}};
    Physical Surface("Rotor{angle_index}_Subdomain") = {point_index+11};

    """
    output_text += line_block

    output_text += f"\n// End Rotor {angle_index}\n"

    index += 1
    angle_index += 1
    point_index += 12
    current_angle += step_angle

# Print the output
print(output_text)

# Write the output to a file
with open("padrao circular.geo", "w") as file:
    file.write(output_text)

Update, I manage to do it directly with the .geo file :
// All dimensions in meters and rads

Lc = 0.0004 ;           // Base char length
Z  = 0.0 ;              // Z-coord

// Rotor data

nbr = 32 ;      // Num. of poles
dthr = 2 * Pi / nbr ;   // Angular shift betw. 2 poles

th0r = dthr / 2 ;       // Ang. pos. rotor
gap = 0.00080 ;         // Air gap width
espar = 0.0015 ;         // Dist. stator-pole top
der = 0.09208 ;         // Ext. diam rotor
rer = der / 2 ;
dir = 0.03175 ;         // Diam. int.
rir = dir / 2 ;

hr = 0.01425 ;          // Pole height
d1r = 0.00426 ;         // Dist. sup
r1r = d1r / 2 ;
d2r = 0.00213 ;         // Dist. inf.
r2r = d2r / 2 ;

distr = rer - espar ;   // Radial dist. of intersect. point

// Stator data

nbs = 32 ;      // Num. of poles
dths = 2 * Pi / nbs ;   // Angular shift betw. 2 poles

th0s = dths / 2 ;       // Ang. pos. stator
espas = 0.01445 ;         // Dist. stator-pole top
des = 0.1529 ;         // Ext. diam stator
res = des / 2 ;
dis = 0.09208 ;         // Diam. int.
ris = dis / 2 ;

hs = 0.0153 ;          // Pole height
d1s = 0.00424 ;         // Dist. sup
r1s = d1s / 2 ;
d2s = 0.0025 ;         // Dist. inf.
r2s = d2s / 2 ;

dists = res - espas ;   // Radial dist. of intersect. point

pAxe = newp ; Point(pAxe) = { 0. , 0. , 0., 15*Lc} ;

// axis

p1 = newp ; Point(p1) = { rir, 0. , 0., 15*Lc} ;
p2 = newp ; Point(p2) = { 0. , rir, 0., 15*Lc} ;

lin1 = newreg ; Line(lin1)   = {pAxe,p1} ;
arc1 = newreg ; Circle(arc1) = {p1,pAxe,p2} ;
lin2 = newreg ; Line(lin2)   = {p2, pAxe} ;

Physical Line("sft_1") = {lin1};
Physical Line("sft_2") = {lin2};
Physical Line("sft_rlm") = {arc1};

reg1 = newreg ; Curve Loop(reg1) = {lin1,arc1,lin2} ; // shaft
reg2 = newreg ; Plane Surface(reg2) = {reg1} ; // shaft

Physical Surface("SFT") = {reg2};

// Rotor lateral sides

p3 = newp ; Point(p3) = { rer-gap, 0.     , 0., Lc} ;
p4 = newp ; Point(p4) = { 0.     , rer-gap, 0., Lc} ;

lin3 = newreg ; Line(lin3)   = {p1, p3} ;
arc2 = newreg ; Circle(arc2) = {p3,pAxe,p4} ;
lin4 = newreg ; Line(lin4)   = {p4, p2} ;

Physical Line("rlm_1") = {lin3};
Physical Line("rlm_2") = {lin4};
Physical Line("rlm_gap") = {arc2};

// Air gap

p5 = newp ; Point(p5) = { ris, 0. , 0., Lc} ;
p6 = newp ; Point(p6) = { 0. , ris, 0., Lc} ;

lin5 = newreg ; Line(lin5) = {p3, p5} ;
lin6 = newreg ; Line(lin6) = {p6, p4} ;
arc3 = newreg ; Circle(arc3) = {p5,pAxe,p6} ;

Physical Line("gap_1") = {lin5};
Physical Line("gap_2") = {lin6};
Physical Line("gap_slm") = {arc3};

// Stator exterior

p7 = newp ; Point(p7) = { res, 0. , 0. , 15*Lc } ;
p8 = newp ; Point(p8) = { 0. , res, 0. , 15*Lc } ;

lin7 = newreg ; Line(lin7)   = {p5, p7} ;
arc4 = newreg ; Circle(arc4) = {p7,pAxe,p8} ;
lin8 = newreg ; Line(lin8)   = {p8, p6} ;

Physical Line("slm_1") = {lin7};
Physical Line("slm_2") = {lin8};
Physical Line("slm_frm") = {arc4};

PP1 = p5 ; PPB = p6 ;

// rotor poles

D1r = distr ;
Hr  = hr ;
R1r = r1r ;
R2r = r2r ;

i = 0;

For(1:nbr/4)
    i++ ;
    th = th0r + (i - 1) * dthr ;
    XS1r = (D1r) * Cos(th) ;                                    //x Sup. top
    YS1r = (D1r) * Sin(th) ;                                    //y Sup. top

    dth = Pi - ArcCos((R1r - R2r) / (Hr - R1r - R2r)) ;

    XA1r = (D1r - R1r) * Cos(th) + R1r * Cos(th - dth) ;        //x Sup. righrt point
    YA1r = (D1r - R1r) * Sin(th) + R1r * Sin(th - dth) ;        //y Sup. righrt point
    XA2r = (D1r - Hr + R2r) * Cos(th) + R2r * Cos(th - dth) ;   //x Inf. righrt point
    YA2r = (D1r - Hr + R2r) * Sin(th) + R2r * Sin(th - dth) ;   //y Inf. righrt point
    XB1r = (D1r - R1r) * Cos(th) + R1r * Cos(th + dth) ;        //x Sup. left point
    YB1r = (D1r - R1r) * Sin(th) + R1r * Sin(th + dth) ;        //y Sup. left point
    XB2r = (D1r - Hr + R2r) * Cos(th) + R2r * Cos(th + dth) ;   //x Inf. left point
    YB2r = (D1r - Hr + R2r) * Sin(th) + R2r * Sin(th + dth) ;   //y Inf. left point

    // Pole

    p6 = newp ; Point(p6) = { XA2r , YA2r, 0., 3*Lc} ;
    p7 = newp ; Point(p7) = { XA1r , YA1r, 0., Lc} ;
    p8 = newp ; Point(p8) = { XS1r , YS1r, 0., Lc} ;
    p9 = newp ; Point(p9) = { XB1r , YB1r, 0., Lc} ;
    p10 = newp ; Point(p10) = { XB2r , YB2r, 0., 3*Lc} ;

    lin9 = newreg ; Line(lin9)    = {p6,p7} ;
    lin10 = newreg ; Line(lin10)    = {p7,p8} ;
    lin11 = newreg ; Line(lin11)    = {p8,p9} ;
    lin12 = newreg ; Line(lin12)    = {p9,p10} ;
    lin13 = newreg ; Line(lin13)    = {p10,p6} ;

    reg1 = newreg ; Curve Loop(reg1) = {lin9,lin10,lin11,lin12,lin13};
    reg2 = newreg ; Plane Surface(reg2) = {reg1};
EndFor

// stator poles

D1s = dists ;
Hs  = hs ;
R1s = r1s ;
R2s = r2s ;

i=0 ;

For(1:nbs/4)
    i++ ;
    th = th0s + (i - 1) * dths ;
    XC1s = (D1s - R1s) * Cos(th) ;        //x Sup. circle center
    YC1s = (D1s - R1s) * Sin(th) ;        //y Sup. circle center

    XS1s = (D1s) * Cos(th) ;              //x Sup. circle top
    YS1s = (D1s) * Sin(th) ;              //y Sup. circle top

    dth = Pi - ArcCos((R1s - R2s) / (Hs - R1s - R2s)) ;

    XA1s = XC1s + R1s * Cos(th - dth) ;   //x Sup. right point
    YA1s = YC1s + R1s * Sin(th - dth) ;   //y Sup. right point
    XA2s = (D1s - Hs + R2s) * Cos(th) + R2s * Cos(th - dth) ;     //x Inf. right point
    YA2s = (D1s - Hs + R2s) * Sin(th) + R2s * Sin(th - dth) ;   //y Inf. right point
    XB1s = XC1s + R1s * Cos(th + dth) ;   //x Sup. left point
    YB1s = YC1s + R1s * Sin(th + dth) ;   //y Sup. left point
    XB2s = (D1s - Hs + R2s) * Cos(th) + R2s * Cos(th + dth) ;     //x Inf. left point
    YB2s = (D1s - Hs + R2s) * Sin(th) + R2s * Sin(th + dth) ;   //y Inf. left point

    // Pole

    p11 = newp ; Point(p11) = { XA2s , YA2s, 0., 3*Lc} ;
    p12 = newp ; Point(p12) = { XA1s , YA1s, 0., Lc} ;
    p13 = newp ; Point(p13) = { XS1s , YS1s, 0., Lc} ;
    p14 = newp ; Point(p14) = { XC1s , YC1s, 0., Lc} ;
    p15 = newp ; Point(p15) = { XB1s , YB1s, 0., 3*Lc} ;
    p16 = newp ; Point(p16) = { XB2s , YB2s, 0., 3*Lc} ;

    lin14 = newreg ; Line(lin14)    = {p11,p12} ;
    arc5 = newreg ; Circle (arc5) = {p12,p14,p13} ;
    arc6 = newreg ; Circle (arc6) = {p13,p14,p15} ;
    lin15 = newreg ; Line(lin15)    = {p15,p16} ;
    lin16 = newreg ; Line(lin16)    = {p16,p11} ;

    reg3 = newreg ; Curve Loop(reg3) = {lin14,arc5,arc6,lin15,lin16};
    reg4 = newreg ; Plane Surface(reg4) = {reg3};
EndFor

Curve Loop(145) = {8,-2,6,7}; //rotor
Plane Surface(146) = {145,69,62,55,48,41,34,27,20}; //rotor
Physical Surface("RLM") = {146};

Curve Loop(147) = {-7,9,11,10}; //air gap
Plane Surface(148) = {147}; //air gap
Physical Surface("GAP") = {148};

Curve Loop(149) = {14,-11,12,13}; // stator
Plane Surface(150) = {149,76,83,90,97,104,111,118,125}; // stator
Physical Surface("SLM") = {150};

Physical Point("Origin") = {pAxe};


I manage to do it directly with the gmsh.geo :

Nice, congrats! You might want to post your solution such that other users can benefit from it, directly or indirectly!

I edit the post to include the file so it doesn’t disappear on the comments.
